# Extract a value from Python dict or class

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

I have a variable called "test"

`print test` gave me the following thing.

```
{"confir": null, "created": "2014-11-07T02:25:21.628730", "email": "asdfs@tyekjhsad.ytg", "first_name": null, "paid": "Y", "id": 33, "is_avail": false, "last_name": null, "que_num": 8, "line": 6, "api_uri": "/api/v1/somehinh/54/", "sent": null, "sub_line": 0, "unique_id": "sdsixq"}
```

`print type(test)` gave me this:

```
<class 'tastypie.http.HttpCreated'>
```

`dir(test)` is:

```
['__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getstate__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__module__', '__new__', '__next__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setstate__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', '_base_content_is_iter', '_charset', '_closable_objects', '_consume_content', '_container', '_convert_to_charset', '_handler_class', '_headers', 'close', 'content', 'cookies', 'delete_cookie', 'flush', 'get', 'has_header', 'items', 'make_bytes', 'next', 'serialize', 'serialize_headers', 'set_cookie', 'set_signed_cookie', 'status_code', 'streaming', 'tell', 'write']
```

Now I want to extract `email` from this. How can I do this?

I assigned it a variable, and then tried `variable['email']`, but it is giving an error as it's not a dict. I can't change the value of the test variable, but I need to extract email from it.

Comment: Can you post the exact error traceback message?

Comment: [`tastypie.http.HttpCreated`](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/http.py#L8) inherits from `django.http.HttpResponse` which has a well defined `__getitem__` method in its base class [`HttpResponseBase`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L94). So, it should support key lookups.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tastypie `HttpCreated` is nothing but a little wrapper over the `HttpResponse` class.

This said, you should be able to get a `status_code` back from your `test` variable by doing `test.status_code (should be 201)`. If this is working you can get your data by using `test.content`. Now keep in mind that this is a JSON string that you get back.

```
# Little Example
import json
json_decoder = json.JSONDecoder()
print json_decode.decode(test.content)
print json_decode.decode(test.content)['email']
```

The last one should give back an email address.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you are using the tastypie library for returning Django responses. In your case test, variable is not a dict, but an object that should implement the dict interface.

I've looked through Django and tastypie sources, and yes, this should work:

```
test['email']
```

Also you can try:

```
test.get('email')
```

Also please see the official Django documentation about `django.http.HttpResponse`, because tastypie.http.HttpCreated does not change much of the inherited functionality:

- https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#setting-header-fields

Answer (score -1):

As you are storing a `dict` in the `test` variable, **test** contains a dict, so all you need to extract is `test[key]`. So do:

```
test['email']
```

And in `test` dict if `null` is nothing and then use `None` instead of `null`.

Answer (score -1):

In a dictionary, put **null and false in a double quote**, which acts like a string, so it is giving an error. You can try by the following code:

```
x={"confir": "null", "created": "2014-11-07T02:25:21.628730", "email": "asdfs@tyekjhsad.ytg",      "first_name": None, "paid": "Y", "id": 33, "is_avail": "false", "last_name": "null", "que_num": 8, "line": 6, "api_uri": "/api/v1/somehinh/54/", "sent": "null", "sub_line": 0, "unique_id": "sdsixq"}
print x["email"]
```

Output:

```
  >>> 
  asdfs@tyekjhsad.ytg
```